# Combining Arrays Without Duplicates in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular9

Data of two different APIs are like Array1 & Array2

Array1=

```
[{"ID" : 1  ,"Name": "abc" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" },{"ID" : 2 ,"Name": "bcd" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" }]
```

Array2=

```
[{"ID" : 3  ,"Name": "efc" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" },{"ID" : 4 ,"Name": "hij" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" }]
```

Expected Output:

```
 [{"ID" : 1  ,"Name": "abc" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" },
  {"ID" : 2 ,"Name": "bcd" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" },
  {"ID" : 3  ,"Name": "efc" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" },
  {"ID" : 4 ,"Name": "hij" , "FamilyName" , "Grimes" }]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are the apis being called? The answers to these would help your question, so please add to the question, not just as a comment

Comment: Have you tried: `array1.concat(array2)`?

Comment: What about duplicate?

Comment: These are HTTP APIs

Comment: Beautiful json you have here. Now show us some javascript. Build a [MCVE]! :)

Comment: array1.concat(array2) is not working

Comment: use `combineLatest()` of rxjs and you can get combined value of array from http response

Comment: is the order of **ID** important? is it's type always going to be an integer?

Comment: Are Array1 and Array2 variables that can keep changing and these changes should be reflected in the combined array, or are they the result of an API call that only emits one value and doesn't need a long running subscribe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const expected = [...array1, ...array2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optionally use forkJoin:

```
const books = this.http.getbooks();
const authors = this.http.getauthors();

forkJoin([books, authors]).subscribe(response => {
 // response[0] will be req1 response
 // response[1] will be req2 response
})
```

The other option as mentioned in the comments is using combineLatest:

```
combineLatest(books, authors).subscribe(response => {
 ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
combineLatest(
    observableAPI1,
    observableAPI2
)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(([array1, array2]) => {
        const combinedArray = [...array1, ...array2];
    });
```

Plus, I'd really recommend using types.

Hope this helps!